Написать код, который сформирует массив с вложенными массивами
Напишите программу, которая сформирует следующий массив:
[
    ['x'],
    ['x', 'x'],
    ['x', 'x', 'x'],
    ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
    ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
]

то, что сделал я:
 let arr = []; // Создал массив, в который буду пушить "х"
 for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) //создал цикл в котором будет 5 итераций подряд
 arr.push("x");
 console.log(arr); // Получил "лестницу" массивов
 }


Не могу понять как каждую итерацию цикла пушить в массив. Создать еще один цикл? Создать еще один массив?

в задаче надо пушить массивы строк, а не строки.... вот и подумайте

Если не пользоваться встроенными функциями js, то да, надо внутри сделать ещё один цикл, для формирования массива из N значений

По-моему ваша идея почти правильная, но для достижения нужного результата вам нужно на каждой итерации цикла добавлять не просто символ "x", а массив с определённым количеством элементов "x"
Изменю ваш код с комментариями


let arr = []; // Изначально пустой массив

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let innerArr = []; // Внутренний массив для каждой строки
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        innerArr.push('x'); // Добавляем 'x' нужное количество раз
    }
    arr.push(innerArr); // Добавляем внутренний массив в основной массив
}

console.log(arr);



компактный вариант с Array.from() лучше

Как только отправил вопрос. сразу возникла мысль про вложенный цикл. Только у меня выходило так:
let arr = [];
for (let z = 0; z < 1; z++) {
arr[z] = []
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
arr[z][i] = arr.push('x');
console.log(arr);
}
}

т.е  хотел создать одномерный массив в котором хотел создать пять массивов, максимальная длина которых должна быть пять знаков. Дальше пошел полет фантазии)

Забыл сказать Спасибо)

ваш сценарий z < 1 = z < 5 и i < 5 = i <= z => let arr = []; for (let z = 0; z < 5; z++) { arr[z] = []; for (let i = 0; i <= z; i++) { arr[z][i] = 'x'; } } //push возвращает новую длину массива (а не сам элемент)=> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push  //Каждый шаг вперёд — это уже победа!

да я уже потом на mdn полез, чтобы посмотреть почему длину возвращает) Спасибо за ликбез)


я не могу понять как каждую итерацию цикла пушить в массив

Как вариант...


const n = 5
const a = Array.from({length: n}, (_, i) => new Array(i + 1).fill('x'))
console.log(a)




Но это же явно домашнее задание на вложенные циклы =)

У вас иксы по вертикали, а ТС просил по горизонтали.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, нет никаких вертикалей и горизонталей - ТСу нужны массивы с нужным количеством элементов, про то, как это будет выводиться ничего нет. Кроме того, в консоли Chrome, например, выводятся вполне горизонтально

@Grundy, уже и пошутить нельзя? Или можно?

@StanislavVolodarskiy, без :-D не считается
